# Excel: Check for substring and add value

Tags: vba, excel, macros, contains

I have multiple Excel sheets. The first sheet contains data for total information. The second sheet contains data for all order line items.

I need to traverse the second sheet based on the information in the first sheet and add up the totals from the line items.

**For example, here is the first sheet:**

[image]

**And here is the second sheet:**

[image: ![enter image description here]

I need to:

1. Compare the "Customer" field in the first sheet to both the "Customer Name" and "Customer Alias" columns.
2. If EITHER the "Customer Name" or "Customer Alias" in the second sheet **contains** the text in the "Customer" field of the first sheet, it will compare the "Item" fields.
3. If the "Item" field from the first sheet matches the "Item" field from the second sheet, we add the quantity and revenue and put them in the first sheet.

**The final result should look something like this:**

[image]

This is a very simplified example. The actual worksheet contains hundreds of entries on the first sheet and thousands of line items on the second sheet. Please help me out if you know how to do this!

Comment: I should clarify: The third image did not delete the other table entries. I just didn't include them in the screenshot.

Comment: Please post the VBA code you have written thus far and include your attempts to write the requested tasks. Also, please point out where in the code the program halts / runs into errors / or does not behave as expected. Thank you.

Comment: Also this can be done with formulas if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a formula solution:

Put this in C2:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((((ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$100)))+(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B2,Sheet2!$B$2:$B$100))))>0)*(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$100=$A2)*(Sheet2!D$2:D$100))
```

then copy over and down.

[image]

I realize you asked for a vba solution, but this is here if you want it.